# How can I change the width of a widget in Responsive theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The default footer widget in the responsive theme is 1/3 of the total screen width. How can I make it wider to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the CSS style in the theme options solved it for me:

```
#home_widget_1.col-300 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find `footer.php` file inside `http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme` directory.

in it you can find similar lines beginning with

```
<!--start footer-->
<footer id="footer">
```

there you'll find `<div class="something">` tags.
If you know what you're doing, change the class of the div.

Always keep a backup :)